# What is the fault level of paralleled transformers?

Tags: transformer, short-circuit, fault

When paralleling transformers the fault level at the bus is it the sum of the individual transformer fault level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. The fault level can also be seen as the system impedance to the point of interest.

Consider the following system, consisting of:

- Generator with Z=5%;
- Transmission line with Z=3%;
- Transformer with Z=4%.

In the secondary of the transformer, the system impedance will be 5+3+4=12%. If you place one more transformer in parallel with the one that already exists, the system impedance will be 5+3+2=10%.

Comment: If I get it right, say that the transformers are connected directly to an infinite bus. paralleling the transformers halves the impedance meaning doubling the fault level at point of contact? with assumption same ratings and percent impedances.

Comment: @OMAR, yes. Exactly.